# MongoDb throws an error while importing using mongoImport

Tags: mongodb

Dear MongoDb experts,

So I have an assignment of which the first step is to import a java script file called Grades.  I have the file stored in IPD351 folder in my C drive.  I am running the following command in my command prompt after connecting to the mongo db server:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > mongoimport -d students -c grades <C:\foldername\filename.js
```

But I get the following error:

```
2016-04-18T13:35:04.983-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15
```

Please help!   If the file does not get imported I cannot do the remaining homework

Answer (score 4):

RESOLVED!  I was in the mongo enterprise, typed exit, got out of enterprise and then typed the import command and it worked!   The new line looks like this:

C:\Users\Akhil\mongoDb> mongoimport -d students -c grades

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `<` just ype the file path:

```
mongoimport -d students -c grades C:\IPD351\grades.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do have the file path in there - for some reason stackoverflow is not displaying my file path.   Let me edit the post above to reflect that

Comment: You're adding a `<` before the file path,

Comment: MongoDB Enterprise > mongoimport -d students -c grades C:\IPD351\grades.js
2016-04-18T14:26:19.098-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

Comment: Maybe try downloading the file again?

Comment: Also, try adding `--batchSize 1`

Comment: Did that too  - deleted it put it there again.  I don't think that has to do with it - file is sitting pretty in the designated folder.